# How to structure my javascript/jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am toying around with a pretty intensive ajax based jquery web application. It is getting to a point where I almost loose track of what events that should trigger what actions etc.

I am sort of left with a feeling that my javascript structure is wrong, on a more basic level. How do you guys structure your javascript/jquery code, the event handling etc., any advise for a newbie javascript developer.

Comment: https://medium.com/@valeriychecha/my-jquery-code-organization-concept-a7ba46c0e715

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AMDS!

It's been awhile since first answers got posted to this question and many things have changed.
First and foremost, the JS browser world seems to be moving towards AMDs (asynchronous module definition) for code organization.

The way that works is you write ALL your code as AMD modules, e.g.:

```
define('moduleName', ['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (dependency1, dependency2) {
    /*This function will get triggered only after all dependency modules loaded*/
    var module = {/*whatever module object, can be any JS variable here really*/};
    return module;
});
```

And then modules get loaded using AMD loaders like **curl.js** or **require.js** etc, for example:

```
curl(
    [
        'myApp/moduleA',
        'myApp/moduleB'
    ],
).then(
    function success (A, B) {
        // load myApp here!
    },
    function failure (ex) {
        alert('myApp didn't load. reason: ' + ex.message);
    }
);
```

Advantages are:

1. You only have to include single `<script>` element on your page that loads AMD loader itself (some of them are quite tiny).
2. After that all JS files will be fetched automatically in asynchronous NON BLOCKING! fashion, thus way faster!
3. Necessary modules will get executed only after its dependencies got loaded.
4. Modular (which means code that is easier to maintain and re-use).
5. Global variables pollution can be completely curbed if used correctly.

Honestly, once concept has **clicked** in your head, you'll never go back to your old ways.

P.S: jQuery does register itself as AMD module starting from version 1.7.

More information on AMDS:

- https://github.com/cujojs/curl
- http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition
- http://requirejs.org/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2275-Using-RequireJS-For-Asynchronous-Script-Loading-And-JavaScript-Dependency-Management.htm
- https://github.com/Integralist/Blog-Posts/blob/master/2012-01-04-Beginners-guide-to-AMD-and-RequireJS.md

Comment: Awesome, I will look at this for my next project. Thanks a bunch for adding to this question so much later.

Answer (score 26):

For javascript code I found the following links from Christian Heilmann indispensable

- [The module pattern](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/07/24/show-love-to-the-module-pattern/)
- [Configuring scripts](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2008/05/23/script-configuration/)

I also really like the method described by Peter Michaux [here](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/how-i-write-javascript-widgets)

For jQuery, I heartily recommend reading the guides on [Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and I found this tutorial on jQuery [plugin patterns](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) very good

Comment: I do like the authoring link (which I have to thank you for), but I have to admit I'm not a big fan of the way jQuery plugins do exposing public methods. I think I just find Christian's method of exposing a single public object or Paul's public returns clearer to read.

Comment: Christian just pointed me to another option for the module, even more elegant:
http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/08/22/again-with-the-module-pattern-reveal-something-to-the-world/

Answer (score 9):

To keep my events in control I use a publish/subscribe mechanism

```
jQuery.subscribe = function( eventName, obj, method ){
    $(window).bind( eventName, function() {
        obj[method].apply( obj, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
    });
    return jQuery;
}

jQuery.publish = function(eventName){
    $( window ).trigger( eventName, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
    return jQuery;
}
```

Here's an example of its use

```
// a couple of objects to work with
var myObj = {
    method1: function( arg ) {
        alert( 'myObj::method1 says: '+arg );
    },
    method2: function( arg1, arg2 ) {
        alert( arg1 );
        //republish
        $.publish( 'anEventNameIMadeUp', arg2 );
    }
}

var myOtherObj = {
    say: function(arg){
        alert('myOtherObj::say says: ' + arg);
    }
}



// you can then have all your event connections in one place

//myObj::method2 is now listening for the 'start' event 
$.subscribe( 'start', myObj, 'method2' );

//myOtherObj::say is now listening for the 'another' event
$.subscribe( 'anotherEvent', myOtherObj, 'say' );

//myObj::method1 is now listening for the 'anEventNameIMadeUp' event
$.subscribe( 'anEventNameIMadeUp', myObj, 'method1' );
//so is myOtherObj::say
$.subscribe( 'anEventNameIMadeUp', myOtherObj, 'say' );


// ok, trigger some events (this could happen anywhere)
$.publish( 'start', 'message1', 'message2' );
$.publish( 'anotherEvent', 'another message' );
```

Comment: While triggering custom jQuery events works, you need to consider how slow it is to use the DOM as your event source.  Consider using [a PubSub plugin](http://higginsforpresident.net/js/static/jq.pubsub.js) after you take a look at the [metrics on PubSub using memory events versus jQuery DOM events](http://weblog.bocoup.com/publishsubscribe-with-jquery-custom-events).

Answer (score 6):

I definitely recommend reading up on the object literal pattern in addition to the module pattern; here's a good writeup:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/show-love-to-the-object-literal

Comment: It looks like the link is broken :(

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($, window, slice)
{

    $.subscribe = function(eventName, obj, method)
    {
        $(window).bind(eventName, function()
        {
            obj[method].apply(obj, slice.call(arguments, 1));
        });
        return $;
    };

    $.publish = function(eventName)
    {
        $(window).trigger(eventName, slice.call(arguments, 1));
        return jQuery;
    };

})(jQuery, window, Array.prototype.slice);
```

Comment: @Akzhan, see the comments I posted to @meouw.  Using DOM events is slow compared to an in-memory alternative.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing answers, here's a [great post](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) that covers more advanced techniques that build on the Module Pattern.

Once your Javascript code reaches a certain size, you'll inevitably want to refactor it by breaking it into multiple files / modules / sub-modules. If you're not sure how to accomplish this using the module pattern, this article is a must-read.

Answer (score 1):

My js files usually follow a naming convention similar to this :

- xxx.utility.js
- mypage.events.js
- xxx.common.js
- /lib/
- /OS-DoNotDistribute/lib/

Where

- 'mypage' is the name of the html,
  aspx, php, etc file.
- 'xxx' is the concept.  (i.e. orders.common.js)
- 'utility' signifies it's a reusable
  library script (i.e. ajax.utility.js, controlfader.utility.js)
- 'common' is reusable functionality
  for this app, but not reusable across
  other projects
- 'lib' is a subdirectory for any external or library scripts
- 'OS-DoNotDistribute' is a subdirectory to ensure no OS licensed code is distributed if the app is ever sold.

Also, for ajax, I have a special naming convention for call back functions, so it's easy to tell what they are.

I'm not sure it that's close to what you were looking for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: You mention special naming convention for ajax callback functions. Please ellaborate. I use Ajax and a couple of utility files that hold stuff like app state, and wrapper functions for ajax calls. But then, especially with JQuery, a callback needs to do different things, among others if click a button do this with server response, if no response, show this view, if response then show that view and populate that view with incoming response data.

Comment: Sorry brat, but I don't remember.  That was 12 years ago.  I haven't worked on much js recently, but in all honesty, if I were to do a js app now, I don't know how many of these conventions I'd still be using.  js development has evolved significantly in the past 12 years.  I'm now wondering if I should delete this answer.

Comment: No prob. But please dont delete. I called my folder "external" and saw your idea of "lib". Makes much more sense. same thing with utility and my equivalent "shared". Shure I should have seen it all over in other code. But your post gonna make me rename to those more sensible names :). I'm shure others can get some gain aswell, even from older posts :).

Answer (score 1):

I really like these articles:

http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

They helped me to understand how telerik creates extensions for asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of AMDs (see  [nix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127152/270274)).

But I typically compile all my JS files into one JS file.
In that case the asynchronous part is not needed. So I wrote a little "Infile Module Loader".

Here it is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/a-little-infile-amd

Answer (score 0):

We can use mvc pattern in our javascript-jquery applications. 
(Backbone.js, knockout.js vs.... ) are mature libraries we can use for this aim.