# Structuring a medium/small sized javascript program

Tags: javascript, canvas

So as a pet project I'm planning on making a simple game using AJAX, Javascript and the Canvas element. While I do have javascript experience it is mostly in very small snippets for sites. I come from a Java background and don't want to start doing this in a "Java" way. Is there any resources that will help me structure and layout my code in a way befitting javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this question:

[How to structure my javascript/jquery code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528648/how-to-structure-my-javascript-jquery-code)