# Structure of programs?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok I trying to learn javascript for my first language but I'm having trouble with the logic/structure of "programming". I know almost everything in javascrupt I can write statements/loops/arrays/objects/ect... but I can't wrap my head around how to use it or put it into action and I can't find what I looking for on the web.

So I guess my question is how do you structure a program in javascript?

does it go like:

variables go here

functions go here

arrays go here

ect...

I just dont get it..

Comment: IMHO: **VERY BAD** choice for learning a programming language

Comment: possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528648/how-to-structure-my-javascript-jquery-code

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't think that's necessarily true. JavaScript has its quirks, but it can be very expressive, and provides a pretty "friendly" vehicle for teaching functional programming principles (esp. given that, because it's embedded in web browsers, there's a ready made "workbench" with facilities for engaging graphical feedback etc).  Disclaimer: I'm currently teaching web programming to some novice 13-year-olds, and they're doing fine :-)

Comment: I still insist that JS is a language that will teach you **BAD** programming habits, and that's bad for a learner. I know this because I started learning programming with BASIC, and now I regret having lost so much time re-learning what I learned wrong. If you want to learn functional programming (which I don't recommend either for a beginner) then go with Haskell or LISP. I strongly suggest imperative programming for beginners, because it's the simplest paradigm, close to how a computer operates and does not have that much abstraction. But this is only my opinion anyway.

Comment: @m0skit0, i think JS is one of the **best** choices for a first programming language. It's got event-oriented programming, cross-browser inconsistencies, inconsistent support, atypical scope, dynamic typing and automatic passing by reference. So many important things to learn about to have a true understanding of how programming works.

Comment: I understand you're a JS professional and might like it, so do I with other languages but I don't recommend them for learning. I think you forgot when you were still learning programming. Anyway, I'm off this discussion because it's too much off-topic.

Comment: @m0skit0, I wrote my comment before seeing your second comment. I will say this about *every programming language ever*: If you learn wrong (taught poorly, bad references, insufficient understanding of core concepts) you will pick up bad programming habits. It's not exclusive to JavaScript.

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, but Javascript is particularly susceptible to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you **must** start with javascript as a programming language, then a good reference for having good structure and habits for your javascript code would be Douglas Crockford's [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). There are a lot of gotchas in javascript, and Crockford is meticulous about style and structure in it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't stress enough how important a good resource is for learning a language.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is wonderful for learning about each of the available objects/methods. Additionally, treat [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) as required reading.

Use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Ask lots of questions.

As for the actual structure of the program:

```
//wrap your code in a self-executing closure to prevent global namespace pollution
(function () {
  //use strict because it's good to brush your teeth
  "use strict"
  //initialize all vars at top of functions
  var a, b, c, d;

  //declare your functions after your variables
  function foo(bar, baz) {
    var fizz, buzz;

    function subfunction() {
      //some code
    }

    //more code
  }

  //whatever code needs to run should follow function declarations
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = foo(a, b);

  //if you need to make something globally accessible, do it explicitly
  window.foo = foo;
}());
```

Also: HTML, CSS, and JS work together in an MVC pattern if you use them correctly. Keep your HTML in `.html` files, your CSS in `.css` files, and your JavaScript in `.js` files. Don't use inline events `<body onload="whatever();">` breaks the separation of content from style from interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to define a structure for a program without specifying what it will do, what will be its size, extensibility, purpose etc.

That said, a good rule of thumb for (local) variables is to define them at the beginning of the function. Because javascript doesn't use a block scope like other C-like language, all of the variable declarations are internally shifted to the beginning of the function anyway.

As for functions, it is usually good to organize them into objects or modules using common functionality and data as a base (javascript is an object oriented language, so pretty much all OOP principles apply here).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a step back and ask Why JS as you're first language?  If you're going to spend your career as a script kiddie (I mean no offence, some very clever people are script kiddies) then carry on.  However if you want to get into server side / desktop development then you will find the transition to something like Java or .Net very hard.  JS is a first-class language and unless you're just going stay within the family (F#, python, ruby, etc) moving to Object Orientation is very hard.  If you really want to learn how to program check out [Alice](http://www.alice.org/), you'll have a lot of fun too.  Anyway back to the question:

```
function myFunc(param) {
    ....
}
```

or

```
(function(){
     . . . .
     function anotherFunc() {
        . . . . .
     }

}())
```

or

```
var myFunction = function() {
  . . . . . 
}
```

All of these structure are valid under different circumstances and as Thomas states, one size doesn't fit all.

Comment: well I'm learning it because I am 25 (kind of old to start programming...) but I want to get in to web developement with JS/ajax i plan on moving to PHP once I learn JS...

Comment: Na, you're just a baby ;)  Get straight to PHP and HTML 5 it rocks.  Be warned though, programming isn't a job, it a way of life.  It's very creative and hard to give up